# Missing System.Scripting in VS.Net 2010-Where can I find it?

Tags: c#, idynamicobject

I installed VS.Net 2010 to play around with some of the new C# features and I'm trying to use the IDynamicObject interface but I can't because it can't find the System.Scripting namespace. What do I need to install to get this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think possibly this has been renamed:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.idynamicmetaobjectprovider(VS.100).aspx

but perhaps someone more in tune with this knows for sure.  Just sharing in case it helps unblock you.

(I know the DLR is in .Net 4.0 and VS2010-Beta2, since they just release matching updates of Iron Python/Ruby that run atop it.)

Comment: I had to build the DLR and install it to get it going but it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can download the DLR libraries from [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/dlr).  I believe they were supposed to be built into .NET 4.0, I'm not sure why they aren't in VS2010, perhaps they are not in the beta.  In any case, I have been using the codeplex libraries for my experimentation, they are supposed to be the same as the .NET 4.0 version (plus some extra hosting features).  They also have some reasonably good documentation on how to use it.

Edit:
Additionally, you can use the codeplex libraries with VS2008.